# How to copy Values from sheets to slides using Google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I am working on a slide that would take dynamic data from Google sheet.

1. I want to keep the slide template
2. Update the slide values in real-time

I want to use Google app scripts to connect the data from the sheet to the slide. I am new to Java Scripts and following a [tutorial online](https://www.upbuild.io/blog/inject-google-sheets-data-into-slides/) to achieve this but with no luck.

My 2 files are set up as follows[image]

and the [slides I am working on can be found here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1kMPSt03w5xzl6bPS8sUXR7-CGrlilrrYhjKY92y4SaY/edit#slide=id.p)

[A copy of the data can also be found here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UccsFtqKKsXhlus4-02dXfJP0ECcCsBUmLNZajJnS_4/edit#gid=20492)

[The tutorial I am following is found in this link](https://www.upbuild.io/blog/inject-google-sheets-data-into-slides/)

Below is the code I have implemented but the problem is it does not work and tries to create multiple pages and repeat same value on each page. I only want one page with the values updated from the sheet
Your help would be grately appareciated. Thank you

```js
function generateLandingPagesReport() {
  var dataSpreadsheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UccsFtqKKsXhlus4-02dXfJP0ECcCsBUmLNZajJnS_4/edit"; //make sure this includes the '/edit at the end
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(dataSpreadsheetUrl);
  var deck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('metrics'); // sheet name
  var values = sheet.getRange('C4:L12').getValues(); // range for values
  var slides = deck.getSlides();
  var templateSlide = slides[0];
  var presLength = slides.length;
 
  values.forEach(function(page){
  if(page[0]){
   
   var Current = page[2];
   var Target = page[3];
   var Emea = page[5];
   var Depac = page[7];
   var Emma = page[9];
   var Comment = page[11];
   
 
   templateSlide.duplicate(); //duplicate the template page
   slides = deck.getSlides(); //update the slides array for indexes and length
   newSlide = slides[2]; // declare the new page to update
   
   
   var shapes = (newSlide.getShapes());
       shapes.forEach(function(shape){
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{Current}}',Current);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{Target}}',Target);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{Emea}}',Emea);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{Depac}}',Depac)
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{Emma}}',Emma);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{Comment}}',Comment);
       
    });
   presLength = slides.length;
   newSlide.move(presLength);
  } // end our conditional statement
  }); //close our loop of values

//Remove the template slide
templateSlide.remove();
 
}
```

Comment: I think that in your current script, `duplicate()` is used in the loop. By this, new slide is inserted every loop. I think that this is one of several reasons of your issue. And, unfortunately, I couldn't see the sample of `and the slides I am working on can be found here`. I cannot understand about your actual situation from the image. So in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you explain about the detail of your Google Slides?

Comment: I noticed that your sample Google Slides can be seen. Thank you for it. By this, I could understand about your situation. So I proposed a method for achieving your goal as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, Thank you very much for taking the time to work on this problem. From your screenshot, this is exactly what I want to achieve.  The only issue is when I run the sample code it does not replace the placeholders on the slide. when I do Logger.log(obj), I see the values from the spreadsheet correctly mapped to each agent and geography. However, the slide does not update with those values. Could you crosscheck again for me or do I need to make changes for it to work from my end? Thank your very much for your effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert the table from Google Spreadsheet to Google Slides.

  - As the sample situation, you want to achieve as follows. This is from your question.

    [image]
- When I saw your sample situation, I can confirm that there are 2 values of `Samuel Tuffuor` in Google Slides. From this situation, you want to put the values to the Google Slides using the row titles of `METRIC`.

### Modification points:

- In your current script,

  - `duplicate()` is used in the loop. By this, new slide is inserted every loop. I think that this is one of several reasons of your issue.
  - At 1st loop of `values.forEach()`, all values are replaced. Because in the template of your Google Slides, `{{current}}`, `{{Target}},` {{Emea}}`,` {{Depac}}`,` {{Emma}}`and`{{Comment}}`of each row is replaced by each`replaceAllText`.
  - In this case, it is required to distinguish `{{current}}`, `{{Target}},` {{Emea}}`,` {{Depac}}`,` {{Emma}}`and`{{Comment}}` of each row.

In order to distinguish the values of each row of template of Google Slides, I would like to propose to group each row.

### Usage:

#### 1. Grouping each row of template of Google Slides.

Please group each row of template of Google Slides as follows. The red dotted line is the groups. In your sample Google Slides, 9 groups are created. Using these groups, the values retrieved from Google Spreadsheet are replaced with the placeholders of each group.

[image]

#### 2. Sample script.

In order to replace the values retrieved from Google Spreadsheet with the place holders of each row of Google Slides, I modified your script as follows.

```
function generateLandingPagesReport() {
  var dataSpreadsheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UccsFtqKKsXhlus4-02dXfJP0ECcCsBUmLNZajJnS_4/edit";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(dataSpreadsheetUrl);
  var deck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  
  // 1. Retrieve values from Google Spreadsheet.
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('metrics');
  var values = sheet.getRange('A4:L12').getDisplayValues(); // or .getValues();
  
  // 2. Create an object for using replacing the values.
  var obj = values.reduce((o, [a,,c,d,,f,,h,,j,,l]) => Object.assign(o, {[a.trim()]: {"{{current}}": c, "{{Target}}": d, "{{Emea}}": f, "{{Depac}}": h, "{{Emma}}": j, "{{Comment}}": l}}), {});

  // 3. Replace values for each group.
  var slides = deck.getSlides();
  var templateSlide = slides[0];
  var groups = templateSlide.getGroups();
  groups.forEach(g => {
    var c = g.getChildren();
    var key = "";
    var r = new RegExp(/{{\w.+}}/);
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      var t = c[i].asShape().getText().asString().trim();
      if (!r.test(t)) {
        key = t;
        break;
      }
    }

    // I modified below script as the additional modification.
    if (obj[key]) {
      c.forEach(h => {
        var t = h.asShape().getText().asString().trim();
        if (r.test(t)) h.asShape().getText().setText(obj[key][t]);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

The flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. Retrieve values from Google Spreadsheet.
2. Create an object for using replacing the values.
3. Replace values for each group.

#### 3. Result.

When the modified script is used for your sample Google Spreadsheet and the sample Google Slides with grouping each row, the following result is obtained. In this case, the 1st slide in the Google Slides is used. So `templateSlide.remove();` is not required to be used.

[image]

### Note:

- In your script, the values are retrieved from Google Spreadsheet using `getValues()`. In this case, 10 % is 0.1. If you want to use 10 %, please use `getDisplayValues()` instead of `getValues()`. In above modified script, `getDisplayValues()` is used.

### References:

- [replaceAllText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#replacealltextfindtext,-replacetext)
- [setText(newText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#settextnewtext)
- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

### Added:

The reason of [your current issue](https://www.screencast.com/t/UWHJe196z) is due to the different row titles between Google Slides and Google Spreadsheet. There are 2 different titles in your sample Google Slides and Google Spreadsheet.

- `Mashal Mashal` and `Mashal  Mashal` for Google Slides and Google Spreadsheet, respectively.

  - `Mashal Mashal` is 1 space between `Mashal` and `Mashal`.
  - `Mashal  Mashal` is 2 spaces between `Mashal` and `Mashal`.
- `Chelsea Great` and `Chelea Great` for Google Slides and Google Spreadsheet, respectively.

Please use the same row titles for Google Slides and Google Spreadsheet. When the row title is different, I modified above script for not replacing the values. So could you please confirm it? When above modified script is used for your Google Slides and Google Spreadsheet, the rows of `Mashal Mashal` and `Chelsea Great` are not replaced.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, Thank you very much for taking the time to work on this problem. From your screenshot, this is exactly what I want to achieve. The only issue is when I run the sample code it does not replace the placeholders on the slide. when I do Logger.log(obj), I see the values from the spreadsheet correctly mapped to each agent and geography. However, the slide does not update with those values. Could you crosscheck again for me or do I need to make changes for it to work from my end? Thank your very much for your effort.

Comment: @astymore Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I think that it is required to replicate your situation. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Google Slides and sample Google Spreadsheet including your latest script for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. By the way, before you use my script, did you group each row of Google Slides? If you didn't it, I have to apologize for this. Because the script is not correctly worked.

Comment: @Tanaike. What if the slide isn't in a group. You can just loop through the object values and assign them to the respective place based on rows and columns? I tried but it puts the whole array object in each cell. I got to find a way to loop and assign

Comment: @karto Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. Especially, I cannot understand about `What if the slide isn't in a group.`. And also, I cannot understand about ` I tried but it puts the whole array object in each cell. I got to find a way to loop and assign`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, can you provide the sample Google Slides and sample Google Spreadsheet including your latest script for replicating your current issue? I would like to confirm your current situation.

Comment: @Tanaike.just posted what I was trying. not working well. it just puts all the object array into the cell of the slide

Comment: @karto Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. When I could understand about it and find the solution, I would like to answer it. By the way, I have to apologize. Now I noticed that you are not the owner of this question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. At that time, please remove your answer which is not the answer of this question. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Tanaika, thanks for your reply. I did not group each row of the slide first and sorry on my part. Now I have grouped it and it worked well with the slide with duplicate Samuel Tuffuor. I changed the Samuel Tuffuor to Chelsea Great and run the code and get the error. see the error message in this link https://www.screencast.com/t/UWHJe196z 
Only one row gets replaced and I get the error. https://www.screencast.com/t/UWHJe196z

Comment: @Tanaika, The current sheet, and slides to help replicate the error are 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UccsFtqKKsXhlus4-02dXfJP0ECcCsBUmLNZajJnS_4/edit#gid=20492  and the slide  https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1kMPSt03w5xzl6bPS8sUXR7-CGrlilrrYhjKY92y4SaY/edit#slide=id.g8f0216c205_0_211

Comment: @astymore Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I think that the reason of your issue is the values of `METRIC` in the Google Slides and the column "A" of `metrics` sheet in the Google Spreadsheet. I couldn't consider that you might use the different titles in Google Slides and Google Spreadsheet. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. For this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Tanaika, Thank you very much for all the hard work. Your solution solves the question as posted and works well. The only issue I see now is that when the data changes in the sheet and I re-run the scrips it does not fetch the new changes. This might be because the {{tags}} are already replaced. This wasn't some I stated in the earlier question posted so I accept your and its not your mistake. However, I would be glad if your could there is a way to update the slides with new data from the sheet.
see my proposal in the next comment

Comment: We can duplicate the slide0 and make a copy and update the copy so that any time I want to fetch update, it will use the template slide and create a new slide with the data populated so I can move the populated slide to my presentation
see the problem in the following screenshot
https://www.screencast.com/t/xNXaI0pH the data is updated in the sheet
https://www.screencast.com/t/MlPbc3jATl
But open to your proposal to a better way to continually update the slide with the dynamic data

Comment: @astymore Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But about your new question, I cannot understand. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, users can think of your new question. Also I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.